# HOw to Extract data from smartsheet dynamically into Hive table

Tags: hive

I have my data available in smartsheet location . Month folders and each month folder i have weekly sheets(example smartsheet/October/wk1,wk2,wk3,wk4 files) and i want to load the data dynamically to hive table.Can someone suggest me how to load dynamically.